# What is the difference between "I'm in no mood " and "I was in no mood"?

Tags: word-usage, tenses

What is the difference between "I'm in no mood " and "I was in no mood"? I asked my mentor and he told me they're both the same, but I see that these are different in regards to tense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct!

"I'm in no mood" is present tense, meaning *currently* you are not in the mood to (wash dishes, do paperwork, go swimming, etc.)

"I was in no mood" is past tense, meaning *before the current moment* you were not in the mood to (wash dishes, do paperwork, go swimming, etc.)

Comment: thanks for your correcting my post, and for your answer.